# Will a capacitor of 10uf 250v work as good as a cap 10uf 50v?

Tags: capacitor, component-selection, electrolytic-capacitor

what is the difference between  electrolytic capacitors 10uf 250v and 10uf 50v?

if i connect it to my circuit  with a 9v battery?

will the 250v cap work?  or which is the most preferred for a 9v circuit  xuf 250v or xuf 50v or with voltage <250v?

Does A 250v capacitor has high resistance as compared to a 50v or < 250v cap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the voltage rating is an indication of the maximum the capacitor can be subjected to. Above that voltage the insulation (dielectric) layer breaks down and the device is destroyed.

The capacity (50uF) is the same and from a circuit point of view that's the important factor.

**However,** there may be other factors such as leakage current and inductance that will vary from capacitor type to capacitor type. These may become the reason for choosing one type of capacitor against another of the same value in a particular circuit.

Comment: so higher the voltage rating higher the resistance?

Comment: By resistance do you mean the ESR? If so, there are many factors other than the voltage rating that can be important. You just have to read the datasheet.

Comment: No. The impedance of a capacitor (its AC resistance) depends on the size of the capacitor (in Farads) and the frequency (in Hertz) of the AC. The higher the frequency or the larger the capacitor value the **LOWER** the impedance gets. At DC (or very very low frequencies) they are open circuit. This is where leakage currents can change their effectiveness. The two capacitors would have equal impedances because they are the same value of capacitance (50uF). At higher frequencies this might change as the inductance of one may be higher than another depending on its construction.

Comment: Another item. In general for a given uF the higher the voltage the bigger the capacitor of similar types.